# omnifaces starting before openwebbeans 1.5.0?

Tags: tomcat, omnifaces, openwebbeans

I am using Java 8 / Tomcat 8 / OpenWebBeans 1.5.0 / MyFaces 2.2.8 / DeltaSpike 1.3.0.

As I want to use the openwebbeans-tomcat7 module, I placed the following jars in tomcat/lib :

- openwebbeans-web-1.5.0.jar
- openwebbeans-tomcat7-1.5.0.jar
- openwebbeans-spi-1.5.0.jar
- openwebbeans-resource-1.5.0.jar
- openwebbeans-jsf-1.5.0.jar
- openwebbeans-impl-1.5.0.jar
- openwebbeans-el22-1.5.0.jar
- xbean-finder-shaded-4.1.jar
- xbean-asm5-shaded-4.1.jar
- myfaces-impl-2.2.8.jar
- myfaces-api-2.2.8.jar
- geronimo-atinject_1.0_spec-1.0.jar
- geronimo-annotation_1.2_spec-1.0.jar
- geronimo-validation_1.0_spec-1.1.jar
- geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec-1.0.jar
- geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec-1.0.jar
- geronimo-jcdi_1.1_spec-1.0.jar
- geronimo-interceptor_1.2_spec-1.0.jar
- commons-digester-1.8.jar
- commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar
- commons-collections-3.2.jar
- commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
- commons-codec-1.3.jar

I also love to use the great omnifaces library. So, my webapp has omnifaces as a dependency, in WEB-INF/lib

There is a problem with CDI with the two versions I am using, 1.8.1 and 2.0.
It seems to me that omnifaces is started before openwebbeans is, and so does not find CDI.

With 1.8.1, this issue raises an exception but it is non blocking, as CDI is not mandatory in this version. In the 2.0, it prevents webapp startup, as omnifaces 2.0 has CDI as a requirement.

With 1.8.1, log is :

```
21-May-2015 23:07:17.678 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Démarrage du service Catalina
21-May-2015 23:07:17.678 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.20
21-May-2015 23:07:17.690 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Déploiement du descripteur de configuration /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.20/conf/Catalina/localhost/apps#presences#edit.xml
21-May-2015 23:07:18.914 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addApplicationListener The listener "org.apache.webbeans.servlet.WebBeansConfigurationListener" is already configured for this context. The duplicate definition has been ignored.
21-May-2015 23:07:19.199 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.webbeans.web.tomcat7.TomcatInstanceManager.inject Error is occured while injecting the OpenWebBeans dependencies for instance org.omnifaces.cdi.eager.EagerBeansRequestListener@7dd5f8b3
javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Api type [org.omnifaces.cdi.eager.BeansInstantiator] is not found with the qualifiers 
Qualifiers: [@javax.enterprise.inject.Default()]
for injection into Field Injection Point, field name :  eagerBeansRepository, Bean Owner : [null]
    at org.apache.webbeans.util.InjectionExceptionUtil.throwUnsatisfiedResolutionException(InjectionExceptionUtil.java:65)
    at org.apache.webbeans.container.InjectionResolver.getInjectionPointBean(InjectionResolver.java:271)
    at org.apache.webbeans.inject.AbstractInjectable.inject(AbstractInjectable.java:82)
    at org.apache.webbeans.inject.InjectableField.doInjection(InjectableField.java:65)
    at org.apache.webbeans.portable.InjectionTargetImpl.injectFields(InjectionTargetImpl.java:220)
    at org.apache.webbeans.portable.InjectionTargetImpl.inject(InjectionTargetImpl.java:206)
    at org.apache.webbeans.portable.InjectionTargetImpl.inject(InjectionTargetImpl.java:196)
    at org.apache.webbeans.inject.OWBInjector.inject(OWBInjector.java:57)
    at org.apache.webbeans.web.tomcat7.TomcatUtil.inject(TomcatUtil.java:40)
    at org.apache.webbeans.web.tomcat7.TomcatInstanceManager.inject(TomcatInstanceManager.java:122)
    at org.apache.webbeans.web.tomcat7.TomcatInstanceManager.newInstance(TomcatInstanceManager.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5162)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:581)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1683)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

21-May-2015 23:07:19.201 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.webbeans.web.tomcat7.TomcatInstanceManager.inject Error is occured while injecting the OpenWebBeans dependencies for instance org.omnifaces.cdi.eager.EagerBeansSessionListener@26cf68af
javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Api type [org.omnifaces.cdi.eager.BeansInstantiator] is not found with the qualifiers 
Qualifiers: [@javax.enterprise.inject.Default()]
for injection into Field Injection Point, field name :  eagerBeansRepository, Bean Owner : [null]
    at org.apache.webbeans.util.InjectionExceptionUtil.throwUnsatisfiedResolutionException(InjectionExceptionUtil.java:65)
    at org.apache.webbeans.container.InjectionResolver.getInjectionPointBean(InjectionResolver.java:271)
    at org.apache.webbeans.inject.AbstractInjectable.inject(AbstractInjectable.java:82)
    at org.apache.webbeans.inject.InjectableField.doInjection(InjectableField.java:65)
    at org.apache.webbeans.portable.InjectionTargetImpl.injectFields(InjectionTargetImpl.java:220)
    at org.apache.webbeans.portable.InjectionTargetImpl.inject(InjectionTargetImpl.java:206)
    at org.apache.webbeans.portable.InjectionTargetImpl.inject(InjectionTargetImpl.java:196)
    at org.apache.webbeans.inject.OWBInjector.inject(OWBInjector.java:57)
    at org.apache.webbeans.web.tomcat7.TomcatUtil.inject(TomcatUtil.java:40)
    at org.apache.webbeans.web.tomcat7.TomcatInstanceManager.inject(TomcatInstanceManager.java:122)
    at org.apache.webbeans.web.tomcat7.TomcatInstanceManager.newInstance(TomcatInstanceManager.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5162)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:581)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1683)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

21-May-2015 23:07:19.201 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.webbeans.web.tomcat7.TomcatInstanceManager.inject Error is occured while injecting the OpenWebBeans dependencies for instance org.omnifaces.cdi.eager.EagerBeansSessionListener@26cf68af
javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Api type [org.omnifaces.cdi.eager.BeansInstantiator] is not found with the qualifiers 
Qualifiers: [@javax.enterprise.inject.Default()]
for injection into Field Injection Point, field name :  eagerBeansRepository, Bean Owner : [null]
    at org.apache.webbeans.util.InjectionExceptionUtil.throwUnsatisfiedResolutionException(InjectionExceptionUtil.java:65)
    at org.apache.webbeans.container.InjectionResolver.getInjectionPointBean(InjectionResolver.java:271)
    at org.apache.webbeans.inject.AbstractInjectable.inject(AbstractInjectable.java:82)
    at org.apache.webbeans.inject.InjectableField.doInjection(InjectableField.java:65)
    at org.apache.webbeans.portable.InjectionTargetImpl.injectFields(InjectionTargetImpl.java:220)
    at org.apache.webbeans.portable.InjectionTargetImpl.inject(InjectionTargetImpl.java:206)
    at org.apache.webbeans.portable.InjectionTargetImpl.inject(InjectionTargetImpl.java:196)
    at org.apache.webbeans.inject.OWBInjector.inject(OWBInjector.java:57)
    at org.apache.webbeans.web.tomcat7.TomcatUtil.inject(TomcatUtil.java:40)
    at org.apache.webbeans.web.tomcat7.TomcatInstanceManager.inject(TomcatInstanceManager.java:122)
    at org.apache.webbeans.web.tomcat7.TomcatInstanceManager.newInstance(TomcatInstanceManager.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5162)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:581)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1683)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

21-May-2015 23:07:19.240 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.webbeans.lifecycle.AbstractLifeCycle.bootstrapApplication OpenWebBeans Container is starting...
21-May-2015 23:07:19.242 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.webbeans.plugins.PluginLoader.startUp Adding OpenWebBeansPlugin : [TomcatWebPlugin]
21-May-2015 23:07:19.242 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.webbeans.plugins.PluginLoader.startUp Adding OpenWebBeansPlugin : [OpenWebBeansJsfPlugin]
21-May-2015 23:07:19.246 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.webbeans.corespi.scanner.AbstractMetaDataDiscovery.addWebBeansXmlLocation added beans archive URL: file:/mnt/ssd/home_bis/dev/git/presences/presences_modules/editpresences/target/edit%23%231.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/beans.xml
21-May-2015 23:07:19.252 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.webbeans.corespi.scanner.AbstractMetaDataDiscovery.addWebBeansXmlLocation added beans archive URL: jar:file:/mnt/ssd/home_bis/dev/git/presences/presences_modules/editpresences/target/edit%23%231.0-SNAPSHOT/
```

With 2.0, it is :

```
21-May-2015 23:32:12.076 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.20
21-May-2015 23:32:12.090 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Déploiement du descripteur de configuration /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.20/conf/Catalina/localhost/apps#presences#edit.xml
21-May-2015 23:32:13.389 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addApplicationListener The listener "org.apache.webbeans.servlet.WebBeansConfigurationListener" is already configured for this context. The duplicate definition has been ignore
d.
21-May-2015 23:32:13.641 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.omnifaces.ApplicationInitializer.logOmniFacesVersion Using OmniFaces version 2.0
21-May-2015 23:32:13.644 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.omnifaces.ApplicationInitializer.checkCDIAvailable 
████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████
▌                         ▐█     ▐                                             ▐
▌    ▄                  ▄█▓█▌    ▐ OmniFaces failed to initialize!             ▐
▌   ▐██▄               ▄▓░░▓▓    ▐                                             ▐
▌   ▐█░██▓            ▓▓░░░▓▌    ▐ This OmniFaces version requires CDI, but    ▐
▌   ▐█▌░▓██          █▓░░░░▓     ▐ none was found on this environment.         ▐
▌    ▓█▌░░▓█▄███████▄███▓░▓█     ▐                                             ▐
▌    ▓██▌░▓██░░░░░░░░░░▓█░▓▌     ▐ OmniFaces 2.x requires a minimum of JSF 2.2.▐
▌     ▓█████░░░░░░░░░░░░▓██      ▐ Since this JSF version, the JSF managed bean▐
▌     ▓██▓░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░▓█      ▐ facility @ManagedBean is semi-official      ▐
▌     ▐█▓░░░░░░█▓░░▓█░░░░▓█▌     ▐ deprecated in favour of CDI. JSF 2.2 users  ▐
▌     ▓█▌░▓█▓▓██▓░█▓▓▓▓▓░▓█▌     ▐ are strongly encouraged to move to CDI.     ▐
▌     ▓▓░▓██████▓░▓███▓▓▌░█▓     ▐                                             ▐
▌    ▐▓▓░█▄▐▓▌█▓░░▓█▐▓▌▄▓░██     ▐ OmniFaces goes a step further by making CDI ▐
▌    ▓█▓░▓█▄▄▄█▓░░▓█▄▄▄█▓░██▌    ▐ a REQUIRED dependency next to JSF 2.2. This ▐
▌    ▓█▌░▓█████▓░░░▓███▓▀░▓█▓    ▐ not only ensures that your web application  ▐
▌   ▐▓█░░░▀▓██▀░░░░░ ▀▓▀░░▓█▓    ▐ represents the state of art, but this also  ▐
▌   ▓██░░░░░░░░▀▄▄▄▄▀░░░░░░▓▓    ▐ makes for us easier to develop OmniFaces,   ▐
▌   ▓█▌░░░░░░░░░░▐▌░░░░░░░░▓▓▌   ▐ without the need for all sorts of hacks in  ▐
▌   ▓█░░░░░░░░░▄▀▀▀▀▄░░░░░░░█▓   ▐ in order to get OmniFaces to deploy on      ▐
▌  ▐█▌░░░░░░░░▀░░░░░░▀░░░░░░█▓▌  ▐ environments without CDI.                   ▐
▌  ▓█░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░██▓  ▐                                             ▐
▌  ▓█░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░▓█▓  ▐ You have 3 options:                         ▐
██████████████████████████████████ 1. Downgrade to OmniFaces 1.x.              ▐
█░▀░░░░▀█▀░░░░░░▀█░░░░░░▀█▀░░░░░▀█ 2. Install CDI in this environment.         ▐
█░░▐█▌░░█░░░██░░░█░░██░░░█░░░██░░█ 3. Switch to a CDI capable environment.     ▐
█░░▐█▌░░█░░░██░░░█░░██░░░█░░░██░░█                                             ▐
█░░▐█▌░░█░░░██░░░█░░░░░░▄█░░▄▄▄▄▄█ For additional instructions, check          ▐
█░░▐█▌░░█░░░██░░░█░░░░████░░░░░░░█ http://omnifaces.org/cdi                    ▐
█░░░█░░░█▄░░░░░░▄█░░░░████▄░░░░░▄█                                             ▐
████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████
21-May-2015 23:32:13.645 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Error during ServletContainerInitializer processing
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.omnifaces.ApplicationInitializer.checkCDIAvailable(ApplicationInitializer.java:101)
    at org.omnifaces.ApplicationInitializer.onStartup(ApplicationInitializer.java:50)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5151)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:581)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1683)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.omnifaces.ApplicationInitializer.checkCDIAvailable(ApplicationInitializer.java:64)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: CDI BeanManager instance is not available in JNDI.
    at org.omnifaces.config.BeanManager.<init>(BeanManager.java:106)
    at org.omnifaces.config.BeanManager.<clinit>(BeanManager.java:49)
    ... 14 more

21-May-2015 23:32:13.651 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Erreur de démarrage du contexte [/apps/presences/edit] suite aux erreurs précédentes
21-May-2015 23:32:13.657 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of configuration descriptor /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.20/conf/Catalina/localhost/apps#presences#edit.xml has finished in 1 566 ms
21-May-2015 23:32:13.659 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Déploiement de l'archive /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.20/webapps/edit##1.0-SNAPSHOT.war de l'application web
21-May-2015 23:32:14.649 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addApplicationListener The listener "org.apache.webbeans.servlet.WebBeansConfigurationListener" is already configured for this context. The duplicate definition has been ignored.
21-May-2015 23:32:14.767 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.webbeans.lifecycle.AbstractLifeCycle.bootstrapApplication OpenWebBeans Container is starting...
21-May-2015 23:32:14.773 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.webbeans.corespi.scanner.AbstractMetaDataDiscovery.addWebBeansXmlLocation added beans archive URL: file:/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.20/webapps/edit%23%231.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/beans.xml
21-May-2015 23:32:14.779 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.webbeans.corespi.scanner.AbstractMetaDataDiscovery.addWebBeansXmlLocation added beans archive URL: jar:file:/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.20/webapps/edit%23%231.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/deltaspike-core-impl-1.3.0.jar!/ME
```

The problem occurs only with omnifaces. OWB works in my webapp.

The start sequence is still very fluctuent, depending on the container (see http://javaeesquad.blogspot.fr/2015/03/getting-notified-when-java-ee.html for instance).

I see that OmniFaces already handles Glassfish special case :

public class ApplicationInitializer implements ServletContainerInitializer {

```
    // Constants ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ApplicationInitializer.class.getName());

    // Actions --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    @Override
    public void onStartup(Set<Class<?>> c, ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
            logOmniFacesVersion();
            checkCDIAvailable(servletContext);
            FacesViews.registerFilter(servletContext);
    }

    private void logOmniFacesVersion() {
            logger.info("Using OmniFaces version " + getClass().getPackage().getSpecificationVersion());
    }

    private void checkCDIAvailable(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
            if (Hacks.isCDIAvailableInGlassFish(servletContext)) {
                    return; // Okay. Don't proceed, because GF4 fails to scan JNDI during servlet container initialization.
            }

            try {
                    BeanManager.INSTANCE.toString();
            }
            catch (Throwable e) {
                    logger.severe(""
                            + "\n████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████"
                            + "\n▌                         ▐█     ▐                                             ▐"
                            + "\n▌    ▄                  ▄█▓█▌    ▐ OmniFaces failed to initialize!             ▐"
                            + "\n▌   ▐██▄               ▄▓░░▓▓    ▐                                             ▐"
                            + "\n▌   ▐█░██▓            ▓▓░░░▓▌    ▐ This OmniFaces version requires CDI, but    ▐"
                            + "\n▌   ▐█▌░▓██          █▓░░░░▓     ▐ none was found on this environment.         ▐"
                            + "\n▌    ▓█▌░░▓█▄███████▄███▓░▓█     ▐                                             ▐"
                            + "\n▌    ▓██▌░▓██░░░░░░░░░░▓█░▓▌     ▐ OmniFaces 2.x requires a minimum of JSF 2.2.▐"
                            + "\n▌     ▓█████░░░░░░░░░░░░▓██      ▐ Since this JSF version, the JSF managed bean▐"
```

and in class Hacks :

```
    // GlassFish related ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Returns <code>true</code> if CDI is available in GlassFish.
     * @param servletContext The involved servlet context.
     * @return <code>true</code> if CDI is available in GlassFish.
     */
    public static boolean isCDIAvailableInGlassFish(ServletContext servletContext) {
            return servletContext.getAttribute("org.glassfish.jsp.beanManagerELResolver") instanceof ELResolver;
    }
```

Is it possible to have such a special case for OWB ?
Testing that an attribute is set would be fair enough to me.

Or is it possible to postpone omnifaces instanciation ?

Finally, why not wait for the CDI notification, with a method such as :

```
public class CDIStartup {

    public void postConstruct(@Observes @Initialized(ApplicationScoped.class) Object o) {
        // CDI Ready    }
}
```

Comment: We've seen this before. Correctly integrating OWB in plain Tomcat is troublesome. That's why TomEE exist. It works flawlessly over there. If you really need Tomcat, consider Weld instead. We'll in meanwhile meditate on how to workaround this nicely. A CDI extension is insuitable as it requires CDI.

Comment: I understand your reply and anyway thank you for providing us omnifaces. It is clearly hard to fully support all containers.

But in some places, you can not choose your container. Not so long ago, I could not put jars in tomcat/lib... So...

I do not understand your last sentence "A CDI extension is insuitable as it requires CDI". It seems to me that getting it started by CDI would ensure that this last is available... That would be for 2.0 only, of course.

Comment: > "Correctly integrating OWB in plain Tomcat is troublesome".
Sorry Bauke @BalusC, that's TOTALLY wrong! OpenWebBeans just provides 2 different ways to integrate. A simple 'Servlet' way which works portably even in GAE and other non-EE containers. And then the full EE integarion way. Point is that you totally trashed all standard Servlet integration use cases with Omnifaces-2.0! Go back and remove that check again and be happy.

Comment: See my comment on your answer, struberg.

Comment: So, if I understood well your dialog, you might code an extension, that is a class implementing javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Extension and observing the BeforeBeanDiscovery event (and not the @Initialized(ApplicationScoped.class) I suggested) ? I will gladly help to test that. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OmniFaces needs to change the check code as it is non-portable. The CDI Specification does not define that the BeanManager nor any Context needs to be available in a ServletContainerInitializer. This is highly depending on the target environment and integration scenario and thus highly non-portable.
This is also a regression in comparison to older versions where it flawlessly worked.

Move it a ServletContextListener, or make it a warning and be done.

Comment: CDI is initialized in a `ServletContainerInitializer`. Both Weld and OpenWebBeans do it. OmniFaces has a `web-fragment.xml` with `<ordering><after><others>` to force it being loaded after all others (thus, also after CDI impl's one which doesn't have any ordering, even not a `<before>`). Why exactly does it fail in Tomcat for OpenWebBeans, but not for Weld? I'd like to know this so I can figure the right detection.

Comment: > "Both Weld and OpenWebBeans do it"
 No that's not right, there is no ServletContainerInitializer involved. And I should know it as I wrote most of Apache OpenWebBeans. From the servlet spec 8.2.4: "The onStartup method of the ServletContainerInitializer will be invoked when the application is coming up before any of the listener's events are fired."
And in normal cases the CDI Container gets started in a ServletContextListener#contextInitialized. Only in EE container it _might_ get booted before. #ChickenEggProblem. Feel free to ping me on the CDI EG list to get this officially clarified.

Comment: What about moving your check in a ServletContextListener as well? THAT is guaranteed to work ;) 
You could also probably make this much more easy: You already have an  Extension, so you could also just set a flag in BeforeBeanDiscovery that the CDI container got booted. Key in a static Map could be the TCCL. (of course dont forget about the BeforeShutdown cleanup to prevene mem leaks)

Comment: You're right, OWB doesn't do it in the initializer. I misread the services folder. I'll surely reconsider the listener approach (I initially did that before, but this won't be invoked when webapp has metadata-complete="true", but this can be workarounded by programmatically registering the listener in the initializer). Edit: Extension hint is a good one.

Comment: regarding the matadata-complete="true" there is another trick: if you have a @HandlesTypes then those classes will get processed regardless.

Comment: I created [issue 133](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/issues/133) on this and will medidate a weekend about the right approach and then pickup it when I'm behind my rig again.

Comment: >"#ChickenEggProblem" - Just for completeness I think JPA has a similar issue here, and for the per request initialization (activating scopes and such) JASPIC suffers from it too.

Comment: I am very sorry BalusC, but your fix does not work. I cloned it, tried it and got the error stacks I added to your issue.